# Elasticsearch timeout true but still get result

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout

I'm setting the timeout to 10ms to my search query, so I'm expecting that elasticsearch search query should timeout in 10ms.

In the response, I do get `"timed_out":true` but the query doesnt seem to timeout. It still runs for a few hundred milliseconds.

Sample response:

```
{
    "took": 460,
    "timed_out": true,
....
```

Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something here ? My goal is to terminate the query if its taking too long so that it doesnt put load on the cluster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What to expect from query `timeout`?

Elasticsearch query running with `timeout` set may return partial or empty results (if timeout has expired), from the [Elasticsearch Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_search_options.html#_timeout_2):

> The timeout parameter tells shards how long they are allowed to
> process data before returning a response to the coordinating node. If
> there was not enough time to process all data, results for this shard
> will be partial, even possibly empty.

The documentation of the [Request Body Search parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-request-body.html#_parameters_4) also tells this:

> **timeout**
>
> A search timeout, bounding the search request to be executed within
> the specified time value and bail with the hits accumulated up to that
> point when expired. Defaults to no timeout.

For further details please consult [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_search_options.html#_timeout_2) in the guide.

#### How to terminate queries that run too long?

Looks like Elasticsearch does not have an ultimate answer, rather several workarounds for particular cases. Here they are.

There isn't a way to protect system from DoS attacks (as of [year 2015](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/terminate-long-running-queries-to-protect-the-system-from-dos/23811)). Long-running queries can be limited with `timeout` or `terminate_after`  query parameters. `terminate_after` is like `timeout` but it counts the number of documents per shard. Both of these parameters are more like recommendations to Elasticsearch, means that some long-running queries can still pass through the desired max execution time (like a `script` query for instance).

Since then [Task Management API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/tasks.html) was introduced and monitoring and cancelling long-running tasks became possible. This means that you will have to write some additional code that will check the health of the cluster and cancel the tasks.

Comment: Correct. Even I went through the documentation etc. and couldnt find a concrete answer to it, hence decided to post it here. Thanks for your answer (y).

Comment: is it still the same i.e no concrete way to stop the queries . I could not find anything in the documentation