# Elasticsearch shows not relevant data when sorting by 'long' field by desc

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, long-integer

I have elasticsearch index with 113 million docs (about 133Gb in size)

```
"mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
        ...some fields...,
        "id": {
            "type": "long"
        }
    }
},
"settings": {
    "index": {
        ...
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "users_index",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        ...
    }
}
```

When i do GET users_index/_search
with

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "size": 1,
    "sort": {
        "id": "desc"
    }
}
```

I get response like

```
{
    "took": 1960,
    "timed_out": true,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 113978032,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "users_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "108384632",
                "_score": null,
                "sort": [
                    108384632
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But `108384632` is not maximum id in index because if i search for exact `id=114098981` I get doc with it.
Can anyone help me with this problem? Could it be that because of this size of the index, elasticsearch for optimization does not take into account all documents when sorting? How can I sort documents by id correctly?

When I call same query with filter `id > {max id from first request}`

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "size": 1,
    "sort": {
        "id": "desc"
    },
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "id": {"gt": 108384632}
        }
    }
}
```

I get correct result

```
{
    "took": 3318,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 5793959,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "users_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "114186327",
                "_score": null,
                "sort": [
                    114186327
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I also tried to get results using aggregation, but the results were even weirder.

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "test": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 1,
                "field": "id",
                "order": {"_key": "desc"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "took": 2580,
    "timed_out": true,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 114065377,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "test": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 4918762,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 44050081,
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the "timed_out" field in the response, which means

> Elasticsearch query running with timeout set may return partial or
> empty results (if timeout has expired)

More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49170917/21923926)

After setting "timeout" to -1 I get expected result.

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "track_total_hits": true,
    "size": 1,
    "sort": {
        "id": "desc"
    },
    "timeout": -1
}
```

Also I asked my teammates and found that [default_search_timeout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search.html#global-search-timeout) was set to 2s.